# Proof of limits $\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6} = 0$$

let $\epsilon > 0$ then $\exists K(\epsilon) \ge \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

turing to solve for n:

$\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6} < \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{(1)^n}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1^n}{n^{2/3}}<\epsilon$

I'm not sure how to solve this equation for $n$, do I need to split it up into cases to find the appropriate $K(\epsilon)$ due to the $(-1)^n$ term? not sure how to do that and find the perfect $K(\epsilon)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take the absolue value…

Comment: "$\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$" Sure about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $K=K(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n≥K$:
 $$\left|\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6} - 0 \right| < \epsilon $$

Following what you were trying to do, we get:
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6} - 0 \right|=
\frac{\sqrt n}{n+6} ≤
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$

Then a suitable value for $K$ is

> $K=1/\epsilon^2 + 1$. Indeed, if $n ≥ K$, then $\left|\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6} - 0 \right|≤ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}≤\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/\epsilon^2}}=\frac{1}{1/\epsilon}=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0 $ choose $N$ large enough such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}<\epsilon$ so that for $n>N$ we have$$\bigg|  \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n+6} -0 \bigg| = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+6}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}<\epsilon$$